# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail crashing despite valid file path

Tags: android, kotlin

Wasted hours on this so far so looking for some help. I've had this code working before so really stumped now. I'm checking that the file exists and it does, yet still no joy. I have

```
 var vidIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)

    var g1 = UUID.randomUUID()

    var vidFileName = "$g1.mp4"
    _videoFileList.add(vidFileName)

    var videoFileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)

    var vidFile = File(videoFileDir, vidFileName)

    _capturedVideoPath = vidFile.absolutePath

    vidIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(vidFile))
    vidIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10)


    startActivityForResult(vidIntent, 0)
```

And then handling the result:

```
if (!_capturedVideoPath.isBlank()){

        println("video captured at $_capturedVideoPath")

        if (!File(_capturedVideoPath).exists()){
            throw Exception("File at $_capturedVideoPath does not exist")
        }

        var thumbBmp : Bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(_capturedVideoPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)
```

Always results in the following crash (testing on a real device):

```
E/ExceptionHandler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/084ea076-995f-4818-9536-4a9184167ccf.mp4 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.reels.videocapture/com.example.live.videocapture.ShootVideoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ThumbnailUtils.createVid…deo.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND) must not be null
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3773)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ThumbnailUtils.createVid…deo.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND) must not be null
                                                                          at com.example.live.videocapture.ShootVideoActivity.onActivityResult(ShootVideoActivity.kt:97)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6597)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3726)
```

Comment: what is the output of this code is it coming inside the conditional bloack
if (!File(_capturedVideoPath).exists()){
            throw Exception("File at $_capturedVideoPath does not exist")
        }

Comment: Logcat might look weird as that's yet another problem I have, when my apps crash nothing is in Logcat, so I found some code on SO that overrides the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`.  @AbdulWaheed it doesn't throw that exception hence the filepath is good.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who gets here, this was permissions on SDK 23.

I had to request [read permissions from external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for this to work. Not impressed with the cryptic error message on such a mature platform!